# Is every totally disconnected topological group locally profinite?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be a topological group which is totally disconnected.  Then one point sets in $G$ are closed, and hence $G$ is Hausdorff.

On the other hand, we have a notion of a *locally profinite group*, a Hausdorff topological group which has a neighborhood basis of the identity consisting of open compact subgroups.  A locally profinite group is obviously totally disconnected.

Is there an example of a totally disconnected topological group which is not locally profinite?

Comment: $\mathbb Q{}{}$

Comment: I did not formulate my question the way I wanted to, I wanted totally disconnected + locally compact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{Q}$ is an example, as are the irrationals (in the guise of the group) $\mathbb{Z}^\omega$ in the product topology. Both spaces are not locally compact at any point of the space.

Comment: Okay, I realized I did not ask the right question.  I want the disconnected topological group to also be locally compact.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2980909/every-group-of-totally-disconnected-type-is-locally-profinite