# Every group of totally disconnected type is locally profinite?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be a Hausdorff topological group in which every point has a neighborhood basis of open compact neighborhoods.  Let's call this a group of totally disconnected (td)-type.

On the other hand, we have a notion of a *locally profinite group*, a Hausdorff topological group which has a neighborhood basis of the identity consisting of open compact subgroups.  A locally profinite group is obviously of td-tytpe.

Is there an example of a group of td-type which is not locally profinite?

Answer (score 0):

I think $\mathbb Z$ would be a counter example : 
$\mathbb Z$ is discrete thus each point $n$ has a basis of compact open neighborhood given by the compact open set $\{n\}$. 
Howewer, subgroups of $\mathbb Z$ are of the form $n\mathbb Z$.

Comment: But $\{0\}$ is a local base for the identity of compact subgroups.

Comment: You're Right! thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that Van Danztig's Theorem is what you are searching for:

*Every totally disconnected locally compact group $G$ contains a compact open subgroup $H$.*

See [enter link description here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/05/30/van-dantzigs-theorem/) for a proof.